# Botan vs OpenSSL vs Crypto++ for cryptography

Tags: c++, c, cryptography

I want to use a cryptography library to implement RSA, DSA and others. Can anyone suggest which is better if you have used it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My personal favorite is Botan. It allows for as much control as you want.

It allows you to chain several steps together in a "pipe" , where you basically write your data to it and botan first BZip2's it and then RSA /DSA's it or whichever function you want and botan provides.

I like the nitty-gritty stuff, like setting bzip to compress at level 9 , so I mix and match whatever functions I find in Botan with what I pick up from other libraries.
Botan doesn't force much upon the user , and the API is quite sane too.

Also, last one, big ups:

It's reasonably well-documented! ; http://botan.randombit.net/manual/index.html

I've also tried cryptopp under windows, but had quite a few headaches trying to get it to link and work correctly in my projects (version 5.6.0 using MSVC2010) , but according to the changelog, 5.6.1 should've fixed this. Also, the documentation is horribly outdated, the tutorial stems from 2002.

And last but not least I have to admit not having tried OpenSSL, but from what I've heard, it had quite a learning curve, and the API is in C instead of C++. (I Certainly prefer the latter)

Answer (score 3):

I use crypto++ (for AES mostly, not RSA) and it's quite ok. can't compare to others, though

Comment: will I be able to use crypto++ for commercial usage free of cost?

Answer (score 3):

Crypto++ and OpenSSL both implement needed functionality, but, I think crypto++ will be easier to use since it has less code.